# How to input a string in a 2D array in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to input a string in a 2D char array. this is the error I am getting.

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘char’ in assignment
inputArray[i][j] = inputMessage;
```

Comment: why don't you post the code?

Comment: You can't assign a `std::string` to something that's presumably a `char[X][Y]`.

Comment: @remyabel: I think it is more likely that the array is declared as `std::string inputArray[N]`. Obviously, without seeing the code either guess is speculation.

Comment: Where do you want the string stored? In a row of the array? You're trying to assign it to a single item which is a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a complete answer, you should post the code that's causing you trouble.

That said, looking at the error, it seems like you're trying to do something along the lines of:

```
std::string inputMessage = "Some String";
char inputArray[100][1]; //Or whatever dimensions you have

for (int j = 0; j < 1; ++j) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        inputArray[i][j] = inputMessage; //Error, can't assign a string to a single 'char'
}
```

Which throws a similar error:

```
cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'char' in assignment
```

To correct this, you need to assign the value of each character of `inputMessage` to a character of `inputArray`:

```
std::string inputMessage = "Some String";
char inputArray[100][1];

for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 1; ++j) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 100 && i < inputMessage.size(); ++i)
        inputArray[i][j] = inputMessage[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to to insert an `std::string` into a `char` array.
First of all a C string is a `char *` not a simple character `char`.
Try using the `c_str`.
`myarray[0]=astring.c_str();`